# Сервер общается с базой данных с помощью SQL?

Tags: sql, frontend, backend

У нас есть клиент (приложение), которое при заполнении полей и отправки формы делает запрос по определенному url для получения токена и данных о клиенте при авторизации на портале.

Вопрос: сервер в это время делает запрос к БД с помощью SQL для получения данных о пользователе и потом это отображается на клиенте? Только ли через SQL? либо что-то используется другое

Comment: кхм. т.е. вы совершенно посторонних людей спрашиваете: как же то-то и то-то устроено **у вас**. весьма странный вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Не обязательно, так как это может быть также любое API. В большинстве случаев такой метод как раз и используется, чтобы обезопасить базу от выполнения произвольных SQL от внешних клиентов.
Но, опять же, зависит от вашего случая - никто здесь не знает ничего про ваши аппликацию и архитектуру.
Можете проверить трафик любым анализатором пакетов сети (например, Wireshark).

Comment: Да, это я понимаю. но, например, у нас есть бэк на java, а бд - постгрес. Как они общаются между собой? С помощью sql запросов? Просто меня мучает этот вопрос.

Comment: jdbc скорее всего используется

Comment: @FLAT, вы должны понимать, что удаленно вам никто не сможет сказать, как общаются, так как не имеют доступа ни к аппликации ни к сопроводительной документации. Это все равно что если бы я описал вам бы как выглядит страница веб-сайта, а вы должны были бы угадать, каким серверным языком она сгенерирована - PHP, ASP, JSP и т.д. Это невозможно, не так ли? Вам же советую просканировать трафик на интерфейсе между сервером и базой. Там либо будет SQL (может, вызов удаленных процедур), либо, если API, то будет SOAP/REST (если на стороне базы перед ней есть некая аппликация-обработчик, само собой).